# How to add CustomXMLParts in word using C++ interface from word object model?

Tags: c++, ms-word

I'm trying to insert some text in a MS word document's customXMLParts. There are plenty of example done using C# or VBA, but I couldn't find any example usage using C++ interface.

So normally in VBA you just do:

```
ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts.Add "<dataOrigin>abcdef</dataOrigin>"
```

However, if I want to do the same thing using the C++ interface from MSO14. The 'Add' Function interface is slightly different:

```
_CustomXMLParts : _IMsoDispObj 
{
 ...
 virtual HRESULT __stdcall Add (
        /*[in]*/ BSTR XML,
        /*[in]*/ VARIANT SchemaCollection,
        /*[out,retval]*/ struct _CustomXMLPart * * ppPart ) = 0;
}
```

So my question is what is this SchemaCollection suppose to be?
there is a _CustomXMLSchemaCollection type, but it doesn't seem to be compatible with VARIANT type. Or should I just pass the stringfy version of the xml schema?

I tried calling the function in the following way, but it doesn't seem to work and just error out:

```
// ... some initial code to get customXMLParts

BSTR xmlContent = SysAllocString(L"<dataOrigin>abcdef</dataOrigin>");
const char * xmlSchema = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>"
"<xs:schema xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">"
"<xs:element name=\"dataOrigin\" type=\"string\"></xs:element>"
"</xs:schema>";

Office14::_CustomXMLPart * outXML (nullptr);
customXMLParts->Add(xmlContent, xmlSchema, &outXML);
```

Most of example I google seems to be for C# or for VBA, does anyone know what schemaCollection suppose to be or have an example of how to call CustomXMLParts.Add correctly using c++ interface?

Comment: Does C++ have an equivalent of the C# Type.Missing? That parameter is optional, so most vba examples simply will not have it. A schema is used only in very special cases, where one wants to validate input in mapped Content Controls. To use it, a schema collection first needs to be created in the document and at least one schema added to it. The parameter is then a schema object from the collection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figure it out. It was just the customXMLParts's own schema collection.

```
BSTR xmlContent = SysAllocString(L"<dataOrigin>abcdef</dataOrigin>");

Office14:_CustomXMLSchemaCollection * schemaCollection ( nullptr );
customXMLParts->get_SchemaCollection( &schemaCollection );

Office14::_CustomXMLPart * outXMLPart (nullptr);
customXMLParts->Add( xmlContent, _variant_t(schemaCollection), &outXMLPart);
```